# Saves a file as a CSV, then save the file in a different format

Tags: vba, excel, csv

***EDIT***

I think I have found the issue, it is creating an infinite loop within the BeforeSave function which is why it is working in the module and not ThisWorkbook.  I would like to use this in the BeforeSave function though, does anyone have a workaround for this?

***EDIT***

I am trying to run code which saves a file as a CSV, then saves the file in a different format (Excel macro enabled workbook).  This is so access will always be able to see an updated CSV file but will save back as a macro enabled workbook after saving the CSV.  Stepping through the code there are no problems, but when I run the macro in its entirety it crashes.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As 
Boolean)

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ChDir "C:\Users\nmorrow\Desktop\Winery Projects\CSV"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\nmorrow\Desktop\Winery Projects\CSV\Site Water Readings
TEST.csv", _
FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False


ChDir "C:\Users\nmorrow\Desktop\Winery Projects\CSV"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
"C:\Users\nmorrow\Desktop\Winery Projects\CSV\Site Water Readings 
TEST.xlsm", _
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

application.displayalerts = true


End Sub
```

Any ideas on this one, or is it just my machine?

Or if there is another way to SaveAs a CSV file then return it to an Excel workbook after the save?

Comment: What happens if you saveAs xlsm before saveAs CSV? Basically when you save your workbook as csv it becomes macro-disabled, this is probably what causes the crash,

Comment: Yes that makes sense.  Is there another way I could save as a CSV to a directory and return it to an excel macro enabled workbook?

Comment: Also why would it work when stepping through the code but when I use the macro to save this happens?

Comment: It might work differently in debug mode in this particular case, probably because the code is running in the debugger so the latter maintains the code, while in normal mode the code is "lost" when you save as CSV. This is just an *attempt* to explain what is happening, not completely sure, honestly.

Comment: You can eventually create a new workbook, copy the worksheets one by one, and save the new WB as CSV.

Comment: BTW the ChDir statements are useless in your code, since you provide full paths. Better remove them, less code makes debugging easier.

Comment: How many sheets do you have in the _xlsm file_? Is it formatted or plain text?

Comment: There are 3 sheets.  It is just plain text.

Comment: So you cannot save it as _csv_. You will have to copy the sheets 1x1 to another workbook and save that as _csv_.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm new here so I'm not sure if this should be a comment (which I cannot create) or an answer.)

I've done similar things before doing this:

- copy active sheet (data to be save as CSV) to a new workbook
- save new workbook as CSV
- return to macro enabled workbook and save as excel workbook

I don't have access to my code but can provide it later if needed.

Comment: Code example would be nice, I believe I am essentially doing what you are explaining.